# Web application testing using selenium . Need advise on best approach

Tags: selenium, cucumber

My web application to be tested is dashboard reporting application which is getting data from another web application. My approach is to for each field get attribute value and compare the expected and actual values and fail and pass based on that . This would mean switching back and forth between applications . Is that only approach to test in my situation ? Any advise will help .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have web application that’s getting data generated in their and that exact data needs to reflect in another web application . This other application is just reporting tool for first application and is read only .  I need to verify all this data is correct in my second application as per application 1. Data is also getting updated in dynamo Db by first application so maybe I can cross check against that db ? But I have no idea about dynamo db how can I connect to it using Java and get results . Please help I am really stuck .